# Output FFmpeg rawvideo to stdin with lib

Tags: c, ffmpeg, stdin, libav

I am writing a C program using **FFmpeg libav**, and trying to output rawvideo (from file or device) packets to **stdin** so that they can be picked up by another program running on my system.

Any suggestions on how to do this?
For example, can I relate to stdin like a filename and just use *avformat_alloc_output_context2* and *avio_open* like I would when recording to a file?

I there some code reference which deals with this scenario?
Thanks.

Comment: Writing raw video is the same as writing binary data. I don't think your question is related to libav. Please do some research, and ask a question about specific problem (add code sample).

Comment: Actually, the question also about writing to stdin through FFmpeg. As I found the answer, I will share here - writing to stdin is like writing to any file type, but the filename used is "pipe:"

Comment: Here [is example](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/a-simple-way-to-read-and-write-audio-and-video-files-in-c-using-ffmpeg-part-2-video/) for writing raw video to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process in C. I also used it in on of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61148924/4926757). Your question specifies: "writing ... to stdin so picked up by **another program** running on my system". **another program** suggests that you are not going to write the data to FFmpeg (but to some other program). In your next question try to be more clear and focus about what you are asking...

Comment: @HillelRosensweig you should post as the answer if it has worked for you.  This is a helpful tidbit!