# Is there a way to use ffmpeg to make a video presentation with different named files?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I read through the ffmpeg documentation and saw that to create a video from an image sequence you can use `ffmpeg -i image-%03d.png video.webm` but one of the problems I am having is how I can actually choose different images named different things each time for instance a picture named "pilot.png" and another named "airplane.png".

Comment: Using a Python script, you may write the images to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process. Here is an example for [H.265 video encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260182/how-to-output-x265-compressed-video-with-cv2-videowriter) (use `libvpx-vp9` codec for VP9 or `libvpx` for VP8 instead of `libx265`). In case you don't want to decoded the PNG images, you may use something as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61148924/4926757). Make sure all images have the same resolution and have the same pixel format (all RGB or all RGBA).

Comment: Thank you for the information.  So when I am using a sub-process, how can I handle problems involving format codes.  For instance I am calling `    subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i image-%d*.png -vf zoompan=d=(%d)/1:fps=1/1,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -c:v mpeg4 -maxrate 5M -q:v 2 out.mp4'%(timeperimage + 1), shell = True)` but one of the problems here is I need to pass a var for the second format code but not for the first.  How can I keep this behavior with the subprocess?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "pass a var for the second format code but not for the first". The command is a string. Add `shlex.split`

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Additionally, you mentioned the pictures needing to have the same resolution and pixel format.  Is there any way I can standardize all of the images with ffmpeg or do I need another solution?

Comment: You may use OpenCV for reading each image, and resizing it before writing to FFmpeg. In that kind of solution you are writing raw images.